# Derivation of collision term in Boltzmann equation: Trying again

Tags: statistical-mechanics, collision

Can anyone show me a derivation of the collision term in the Boltzmann equation? I don't mean one of the simplified varieties. I mean Boltzmann's full-blown term as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation#Two-body_collision_term).

Update: I asked this question a few days ago and was told that it had already been answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103156/understanding-collision-terms-in-boltzmann-equation).  With all due respect, that link is not at all an answer to my question.  Please notice that I specifically asked for a derivation of the *full* collision term.  The referenced question and answer are certainly interesting in their own way, but since they relate to a *valid but greatly simplified approximation* to the collision term, they are not relevant to the actual question that I asked.

Comment: Hi bob.sacamento. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: The instruction specifically say, "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, *ask a new one*."  And the link to do so takes me to the page for a new question.  And further, my original question was closed.  So you kind of leave me no options here!  But I'll try one more time.